# Setting volume on Audio Unit (kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO)

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

How to set volume on Audio Unit specifically on kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO ?

I saw something for kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer

```
    status = AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerUnit, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Output, AU_OUTPUT_BUS, volume, 0);
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 9):

From Chris Adamson's blog [An iPhone Core Audio brain dump](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/?p=507)

"*RemoteIO does not have a gain or volume property. The mixer unit has volume properties on all input buses and its output bus (0). Therefore, setting the mixer’s output volume property could be a de facto volume control, if it’s the last thing before RemoteIO. And it’s somewhat more appealing than manually multiplying all your samples by a volume factor.*"

Answer (score 1):

if your target  is desktop this will help you http://developer.apple.com/audio/audiounits.html
with iphone target

result = AudioUnitSetParameter ( yourUnit,
                                        kHALOutputParam_Volume,
                                        kAudioUnitScope_Output,
busNumber,
volume,
0);           this will set device volume

Comment: Setting kHALOutputParam_Volume on the remoteIO unit iOS does not have any effect. You'll need to use pion's answer instead. Set kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume on the output of the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code you've got there will set the master out volume, yes.  Instead of `AU_OUTPUT_BUS` (undefined constant?), you can just use 0 for the "0th output bus" (`kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer` only have 1 output bus).

If you wanted to set the volume of *one particular input bus*, you can do so too,

```
AudioUnitSetParameter( mixerUnit,
  kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Input, busId, volume, 0 ) ;
```

Comment: my problem is how to build a graph if the current library uses only one unit and without graph. And you just suggest the same which is mentioned in the question as incorrect